# d3js add svg-seat or box with in an polygon

Tags: javascript, d3.js

How can I generate a coordinates to insert `box` or `svg-seats` given total `box/svg-seat` and no of rows inside the polygon?

**Example:** Add 10 rows and 5 `svg-seat/box` each row inside the polygon

How to write a function which gives axis to insert a `svg-seat/box`?

Is there a interpolate method to which I pass the polygon which returns the points to insert the svg-seat/box?

[jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/Bl_praveen2004/khnb1r7z/2/)

What I have now is grid?

This function I want to pass polygon with rows and  columns, direction(left to right or top to bottom) and align(center,top,bottom,left  and right).
it should return the data with x and y points

```js
function gridData() {
    var data = new Array();
    var xpos = 1; //starting xpos and ypos at 1 so the stroke will show when we make the grid below
    var ypos = 1;
    var width = 50;
    var height = 50;
    
    // iterate for rows 
    for (var row = 0; row < 10; row++) {
        data.push( new Array() );
        
        // iterate for cells/columns inside rows
        for (var column = 0; column < 10; column++) {
            data[row].push({
                x: xpos,
                y: ypos,
                width: width,
                height: height
            })
            // increment the x position. I.e. move it over by 50 (width variable)
            xpos += width;
        }
        // reset the x position after a row is complete
        xpos = 1;
        // increment the y position for the next row. Move it down 50 (height variable)
        ypos += height; 
    }
    return data;
}
```